# About L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

Why should we assume that $g'$ does not vanish on (a, b)? Because, by stating that $h = \frac{f'}{g'}$ has a limit at $a^+$, we already assume that h is defined in a neighborhood of $a^+$, and therefore $g'$ must be non-zero in a neighborhood of $a^+$. What am I missing exactly?

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150039/discussion-on-question-by-ziad-about-lhopitals-rule); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.